# Why does MySQL return rows that seemingly do not match the WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

suppose the user input

```
mysite.com/profile?identity=1
mysite.com/profile?identity=dinodsja
mysite.com/profile?identity=1a
```

getting the value

```
$identity = $_GET['identity']; // identity can be user_id or user_name
```

and i have a simple select query:

```
SELECT * FROM lb_users WHERE (user_id = 'dinodsja' OR user_name = 'dinodsja') AND user_status = 1
```

and it works fine. but the problem is:

```
SELECT * FROM lb_users WHERE (user_id = '1a' OR user_name = '1a') AND user_status = 1
```

when I execute this query it also returns the result **without satisfying the condition**.

Table structure:

```
user_id     bigint(25)
user_name   varchar(50)     utf8_general_ci
```

[image]

**

```
-> Is this a MySQL Bug ? 
-> How can we avoid this ? 
-> What will be the query ?
```

**

Comment: can you post table structure

Comment: You are comparing apples (numbers) to oranges (strings).

Comment: what is the problem to validate user input when you know that the type of the field is numeric? What kind of answer you expect from the community providing a bounty for the question?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I do remember having a similar problem long ago.

First some background: This is *not* a bug. It is actually a feature. Ok, it's one that might lead to such unexpected behaviour, but MySQL is thereby very tolerant w.r.t. user inputs, respective select queries:

```
mysql> SELECT 'a' = 'a ';
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT 'A' = 'a';
        -> 1
```

Therefore, with [implicit type conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html), the result of, e.g, `'1a'` in INTEGER is 1, but also:

```
mysql> SELECT 0 = 'x6';
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT 1 = ' 1';
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT 1 = ' 1a';
        -> 1
```

This feature is also implemented in other not statically typed languages. PHP, for instance, calls this [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). See the [PHP String conversion rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) and this example from the documentation:

```
<?php
  $foo = "0";                     // $foo is string (ASCII 48)
  $foo += 2;                      // $foo is now an integer (2)
  $foo = $foo + 1.3;              // $foo is now a float (3.3)
  $foo = 5 + "10 Little Piggies"; // $foo is integer (15)
  $foo = 5 + "10 Small Pigs";     // $foo is integer (15)
?>
```

See [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp):

```
<script>
  document.write(parseInt("40 years") + "<br>");
</script>

=> 40
```

Nevertheless, the solution to your problem is pretty easy: Just cast the integer to a char and do the comparison then:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM lb_users WHERE (CAST(user_id AS CHAR) = '1' OR user_name = '1')
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT * FROM lb_users WHERE (CAST(user_id AS CHAR) = '1a' OR user_name = '1a')
        -> 0
mysql> SELECT * FROM lb_users WHERE (CAST(user_id AS CHAR) = 'dinodsja' OR user_name = 'dinodsja')
        -> 1
```

I made a fiddle for everyone to try it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2835/14/0

Hope that helps,

-Hannes

Comment: I disagree. This **is** a bug, not a feature.

Comment: And I disagree. This is a feature implemented in various languages. For instance in PHP this is called type juggling. For syntax highlighting I will edit my answer and add a code example. I do think it is very good that these languages are consistent among each other, as they are often used in the same context.

Comment: That might be true for PHP (or other weakly typed languages), but SQL is a strongly typed language (like Java) and this behaviour is not only completely unexpected it also violates the SQL standard which clearly states that an exception has to be thrown in such a case

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MySQL developers have a habit of calling bugs features. I had reported a bug in the partition pruning logic. What i got as a reply was some explanation about the implementation which makes that happen instead of accepting it as a bug. To put it simply my argument was like - the answer should be 2+2=4 and their response was like: the code does 2-2 so 0 is correct. No explanation about why do - instead of + when that is what is expected out of such a query. See: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28928

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. As I am not a MySQL dev, I will not defend this. I just thought it's documented, so they don't consider it as a bug, therefore I - the user - has to cope with it. I think if you could cite the corresponding passage from the standard, this would be a perfect end to the discussion :-) But I do like the idea of documenting flaws as features. "Our software is brilliant! It has thousands of features and comes with an encyclopedia as documentation". "Dude, it's a calculator..."

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's clearly a feature unfortunately. Check this out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html. Using the strict mode should solve most of unexpected behaviours. But it's clearly not a bug since it is built into it. Mysql will do silent type conversions.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: that's the MySQL way, simply call it a feature, then it's not a bug anymore. There are more examples like that....

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that would be a bug if there was no way to disable it. Strict mode should do the trick. It should raise an error on conversion and rollback. I do believe that it's a bad thing. Around 10 years ago, the web community created the LAMP acronym that stands for. Linux, Apache, Mysql, PHP. Since mysql was often used with php, that would make sense that they just copied the behavior from php and kept it as default. Wouldn't that be sad if all of a sudden php programs would fail to work because they forgot to cast to the right type...

Comment: Whoever invented that "type juggling" stuff has made me very, very sad.

Answer (score 32):

The reason for that is because the data type of the column `user_ID` is integer.

MySQL silently **drops any trailing** *NON-Number* (*and anything that follows within*) in the value and that is why `1a` is equal to `1` since `a` will be remove in the value.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/9797)

Comment: ok. thank u. then hw can we avoid this . wat will be the query ?

Comment: @DBK you can handle the checking value in the `PHP`.

Comment: its a user input for profile. user can provide user_id or user_name. so the input is valid. but no data.

Comment: @J W - This answer is straightforward, simple and correct! :-) (besides the typo of user_ID) @DBK - You should avoid using strings to identify a user ('dinodsja', '1a')...  ...The user should not provider the user_id. That should be coded for the system and not the user.

Comment: @DBK as suggested by Aiias, you can add `BINARY` but keep in mind that this will **make also your search case sensitive**. [See Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/9780)

Comment: I realized this (int column dropping non-number value) almost 1 year after I got into PHP. It's such a small thing but it did trouble me a lot when I came across a similar situation

Comment: I consider this a bug in MySQL. Every other DBMS correctly rejects a comparison between numbers and strings that are not numbers. And no other DBMS tries to be smart and removes parts of the comparison value to avoid an error message (at the risk of returning incorrect results)

Answer (score 0):

According to your previous message

> its a user input for profile. user can provide user_id or user_name.
>   so the input is valid. but no data. – DBK Mar 30 at 6:42

I'd recommend testing to see if its an integer and only search the user ID if it's an integer. It's really more of a workaround for mySQL not handling a STRING to INT comparison, but it should work.

```
declare @InputVar varchar(10)
set @InputVar = '1a'

SELECT *  
FROM lb_users
WHERE  
  (case when isnumeric(@InputVar) = 1 then 
    case when (user_id = @InputVar OR user_name = @InputVar) then 1 else 0 end
  else  
    case when user_name = @InputVar then 1 else 0 end
  end =1 )
And 
  user_status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with strings I would use 'LIKE' instead of '=' to avoid this silent type conversion madness. LIKE is made to work with strings so why not use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM lb_users WHERE (user_id = '1a' OR user_name = '1a') AND user_status = 1
```

you get 1 result if you change '1a' to 1a you get this:

*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1a LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1*

This is not a bug, take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot duplicate a primary key and an ID, I test that one and i come up with a running data..did you set the user_id with its attributes like:

```
user_id bigint(50) auto_increment primary key
```

this is not a mysql error.